# Improving item saving throws

Tags: dnd-3.5e

A character is being prepared with the Voidspawn template from the Book of Templates. They have an ability that can cause items to disintegrate on touch. There is an increasing chance per hour that the ability will accidentally go off on up to 10 cubic feet of stuff the character is touching, including the floor, armor, weapons, etc. It is inevitable that it will happen eventually, and I would like to be prepared for it. The items get a fort save against it (DC 10 + 1/2 HD + Cha), are there any methods to increase the saving throws of the items, making them immune to the effect, or being able to avoid the effect in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Have them be "attended" (properly carried close to the body) by a character with good fortitude saves. Or enchant them with powerful (high casterlevel) effects.

From the Rules Compendium, page 106:

> Nonmagical, unattended items never make saving throws. They’re
>   considered to have failed their saving throws. An item being grasped,
>   touched, or worn (attended) by a creature makes saving throws using
>   that creature’s saving throw bonus. Magic items always receive saving
>   throws. A magic item’s Fortitude, Refl ex, and Will save bonuses are
>   equal to 2 + 1/2 its caster level. An attended magic item either makes
>   saving throws as its owner, or it uses its own saving throw bonus,
>   whichever is higher.

I could not find any rules for whether "structural" objects' saving throws are treated differently '(so walls, and the ground, may be in a heap of trouble). You could maybe treat big structures' saving throws as those of animated objects of their size (which, if I remember correctly, make fort saves at a simple +0 modifier) to prevent your party from being buried and killed in collapsing buildings (or falling into a surprise pit) as often.

Alternatively, in your case, maybe there could be an enchantment to specifically protect objects from disintegration-effects (giving the objects a large bonus to the save against them, or immunity to them).

From what it looks, though, your campaign will turn into a low-wealth, high-hilarity campaign quite quickly with that character's ability.

Comment: I know what you mean about the low wealth high hilarity. I could just imagine facing off with the BBEG and suddenly all my stuff, clothes included, is gone.